# How does the method "scheduleAtFixedRate" of the class ScheduledExecutorService work?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying an example using the method `scheduleAtFixedRate` of the class `ScheduledExecutorService`. The code is:

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
        IntStream.range(0, 4).forEach(i -> service.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {try {
            System.out.println(i + " task completed!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}, 
                0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        service.shutdown();
```

The output is:

```
1 task completed!
2 task completed!
0 task completed!
```

Why are not all 4 tasks executed?

If I omit the `service.shutdown();` then all the tasks are executed and repeatedly as well, but it leads to memory leak. According to the docs any before shutdown registered task should be executed.

Moreover, if I pause the current `Thread` for a while using `Thread.sleep()`, then the output contains all the tasks as:

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
        IntStream.range(0, 4).forEach(i -> service.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {try {
            System.out.println(i + " task completed!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}, 
                0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        service.shutdown();
```

Output:

```
0 task completed!
3 task completed!
2 task completed!
1 task completed!
```

Is this the expected behavior of the method `scheduleAtFixedRate`?

**Update:**

When I use `submit` instead of `scheduleAtFixedRate` without delay then the behavior comes close to the expected. Calling `shutdown()` allows all 4 tasks to complete while `shutdownNow()` only 3:

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
        IntStream.range(0, 4).forEach(i -> service.submit(() -> {

        System.out.println(i + " task completed");}));

        service.shutdown();
```

If I refrain from `ScheduledExcecutorService` and use `ExecutorService` instead as:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    IntStream.range(0, 4).forEach(i -> service.submit(() -> {

    System.out.println(i + " task completed");}));

     service.shutdown();
```

then all 4 tasks are always completed whether I use `shutdown()` of `shutdownNow()`.

It seems that the `ScheduledExecutorService` behaves a little bit different on the task submission and perhaps on `shutdown()` and `shutdownNow()`.

Comment: It's not startling that some of the tasks don't get executed (you shutdown the pool prior to them starting), but I don't understand why don't all futures  that haven't run yet (those that have just don't get rescheduled) -- why don't those futures get cancelled (I tried to hook there and only some get cancelled).

Answer (score -1):

Found this in the documentation of ExecutorService.class

> This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to
>        complete execution.  Use {@link #awaitTermination awaitTermination}
>         to do that.

Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425026/shutdown-and-awaittermination-which-first-call-have-any-difference) for more info.
From my PC I found out that sometimes all four threads complete execution. It depends on the time when `shudown` is called. Use `awaitTermination` method if you want to wait for your threads to complete.

When you made your `main` thread to sleep, it took time to execute `shutdown` and until then all the tasks were over.