# how to stop thread in ExecutorService

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice

```
ExecutorService executor = ****;
List<List<Object>> objectGroup = Lists.partition(objectList, 5);
for (List<Object> eachGroup : objectGroup ) {
            CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(eachGroup.size());
            for (Object obj: eachGroup) {
                executor.submit(() -> {
                    doTask(obj);
                    latch.countDown();
                });
            }

            try {
                if (!latch.await(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
                    // todo close all thread in executor 
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
```

**

I want to close all thread in `executor` after 15 minutes but I do not know how to close.

Someone said to use `executor.shutDownNow()` but it will close the executor (I can not submit thread anymore), I don't want that to happen

**

Comment: You want to close the executor service but don’t want to call the shutdown method??? Why not?

Comment: "Someone said to use executor.shutDownNow() but it will close the executor (I can not submit thread anymore), I don't want that to happen"? Why you don't want that to happen? What would be issue?

Comment: I think this may be relevant: [shutdown and awaitTermination which first call have any difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425026/shutdown-and-awaittermination-which-first-call-have-any-difference) Also refer to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Comment: I want to stop/interrupt  the thread work, but not close executor

Answer (score 0):

There's only one way to stop the `Thread` in java: ask it to do so.

```java
new Runnable()  {
   // This status should be checked repeatedly within a process
   if(Thread.interrupted()) {
       // Executore has probably ask to stop
   }
}
```

Further, you have an `ExecutorService` instance. To ask all threads to stop, you should call `shutDownNow()` method. This method will set
`interrupted` flag to all threads in the `ExecutorService`.

***P.S.** Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900387/how-to-stop-all-runnable-thread-in-java-executor-class) post gives the details.*

Comment: The interrupted status should be checked repeatedly, not just upon entry.

Comment: Yes, I have add a comment. I think this is obvious.